# How to obtain gmail messages received after a particular date using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to get gmail messages received after a particular date using Google Apps Script?

Here is my current code.

```
function getGmailEmails(){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("TestLabel");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages(); 

    for (var j = 0; j <messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j]; 
      extractDetails(message); 
    }
  }
}
```

I know we can set limits with getThread(0,50) for example but how can I do it so I can retrieve all my gmails from a specific period of time while also getting it within a certain label from my inbox?

Answer (score 0):

Messages After a Date:

```
function getGmailEmailsAfter(date){
  const label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("TestLabel");
  const threads = label.getThreads();
  const dtv = new Date(date.getFullYear(),data.getMonth(),date.getDate()).valueOf();
  for (let i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    let messages = threads[i].getMessages(); 
    for (let j = 0; j <messages.length; j++){
      let message = messages[j]; 
      let dt = new Date(message.getDate())
      if(new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf() > dtv) {
        extractDetails(message); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Where would I enter the specific date? For example 2021-01-01

Comment: Pass it a javascript Date() object